# gbvs ( Graph-Based Visual Saliency) doesn't work correctly

Tags: matlab

Is there every one who has done Saliency map with gbvs?

It doens't run on my MATLAB 2015a or 2013b, it gives some errors and its designer it's not responsible!

error:

```
 map=gbvs(img);
Undefined function 'fieldnames' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in gbvs (line 60)
mapnames = fieldnames(rawfeatmaps);
```

Comment: That was resolved https://bugsanddebugs.blogspot.com/2009/10/gbvs-graph-based-visual-saliency-how-to.html#comment-form

Comment: Did you solve this through that link you posted? In that case, either copy the answer here for completion, or remove the question as it's not very clear to me what you want.

Comment: I used it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The gbvs matlab code needs some changes as mentioned [here](https://bugsanddebugs.blogspot.com/2009/10/gbvs-graph-based-visual-saliency-how-to.html#comment-form).